# Get path to exe file on py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I am writing a little gui application with Tkinter, which requires me to have a path to icon files. I am planning on embedding the file into the exe that I make with py2exe, and then retrieving it from there. The only problem is that I need to know where that file is. Does anyone know a way of getting the currently running exe file/path? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
path = os.path.dirname(_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of useful links for people coming across this question. The latter provides a nice example -

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I found out the answer! sys.executable should do the trick. It returns the path and filename of the currently running exe, although I must test to see that it works with py2exe.